# Can overusing a trim router be bad?

Tags: router

I have made a planer table that uses a sled on top to use my router as the planing device. After using it for a good 45 minutes to an hour, my $60 Performax router is getting very warm.

Do I need to give it a break? Will I regret for life not giving it a rest because it shall just fry up?

I ask this because normally I would give it a break but there are some days when I am busy and need stuff planed and would prefer not to stop if I do not need to.

Comment: It sounds like you got (only) what you paid for.... cheap tools are cheap for a reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small router like that is not optimal for use in a planing sled.  Small universal motors like that can overheat and be permanently damaged.  If you want to use this method for planing, you should at least look at getting a quality 2 1/2 - 3 horsepower router.  If that is not a cost effective option for you, consider getting another router like the one you have and swapping them out every 15 minutes or so.

There is a reason induction motors are used in commercial/industrial systems instead of universal motors - duty cycle.  A quality induction motor can be run for hours at a time with no ill effects.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you're overusing it.  But depending on what your situation is, that might be okay.

If you plan to do this a lot, and you can make an up front investment, a better quality router will be much nicer to use and will last for years.

If this is a hobby you're trying out, and the router + sled is giving you a satisfactory result, then go hog wild, man.

The internet will always be glad to give you a way to spend more money, and they're usually right at the professional level.  In my shop, I can afford to replace a burnt out $60 router every 2 or 3 years.  I buy used stuff and keep it creative in a way that would never work if this were my living.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: *"The internet will always be glad to give you a way to spend more money"* I'm so stealing that!